# JavaScript and regular expression, only numbers and . ,

Tags: javascript, regex

Regular expressions is not my thing. Hope you can help me here.

I have this right now:

/^[0-9]+$/

and i need to change it, so it will allow numbers from 0-9 and only "," to be in the string 1 time. After the , we can only have as many digits we want but only 2 digits before the ",".

allowed: 66,6666 - 6,66 - 6,6
Not allowed: 666,66 - 66,666abc - abc,666

Hope you can help.

Code:

```
$("#discountCodeAmount").keyup(function() {

        var nAmount = $("#discountCodeAmount").val();
        var kronerExp = /^[0-9]+$/;
        var procentExp = /^[0-9]{1,2},[0-9]+$/;

        if($('#typeProcent').is(":selected") && !nAmount.match(procentExp)) {
            errorDialog("error");
            $("#discountCodeAmount").val("");
            $("body").focus();
        }
        else if(!nAmount.match(kronerExp)) {
            errorDialog("error");
            $("#discountCodeAmount").val("");
            $("body").focus();
        }
});
```

Comment: Any help here?? I doesn't work. :/

Comment: Finally i got it working. Used blur() instead of keyup, and this expression /^[0-9]{1,2}(?:,[0-9]+)?$/; Thanks guys

Answer (score 1):

```
/^[0-9]{1,2},[0-9]+$/
```

Comment: Thats the StackOverflow game!

Comment: does `|` actually work? I thought you had to use `,` to denote a range in `{}` s

Comment: Edited it to be a `,` instead of a `|` in the quantifier.

Comment: alternative would be `/^[0-9][0-9]?,[0-9]+$/`

Comment: Yer but that looks a bit horrible. We should use the language constructs given to us I feel.

Comment: var procentExp = /^[0-9]{1,2},[0-9]+$/; Does not seem to work with on keyup, if(!nAmount.match(procentExp)) {error msg}

Comment: The regex should be correct, but to solve your code problem we would need to see your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
/^[0-9]{1,2},[0-9]+$/
```

Comment: Also there must be able to be 1 or 2 digits before the comma.

Comment: @Marcus: His paragraph wasn't clear on that, but I guess his examples were... fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
/^\d{2},\d+$/
```

Answer (score 0):

Working example

```
    $("#discountCodeAmount").blur(function() {  
        checkType();      
    });        

    function checkType() {
        var nAmount = $("#discountCodeAmount").val();
        var kronerExp = /^[0-9]+$/;
        var procentExp = /^[0-9]{1,2}(?:,[0-9]+)?$/;

        if($('#typeProcent').is(":selected") && !nAmount.match(procentExp)) {
            errorDialog("Der opstod en fejl!","Angiv en procentdel mellem 1 og 99.");
            $("#discountCodeAmount").val("");
            $("body").focus();
        }
        else if($('#typeKroner').is(":selected") && !nAmount.match(kronerExp)) {
            errorDialog("Der opstod en fejl!","Angiv kun tal i feltet.");
            $("#discountCodeAmount").val("");
            $("body").focus();
        }
    }
```